# Where did Hollowface come from, and how was he defeated in Intruders?

Tags: plot-explanation, intruders

I found [Intruders](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1634121/) to be a rather confusing, and intellectually unsatisfying film.  I felt it left too many questions unanswered.  Or maybe I just didn't catch the answers--which could well be the case, considering I watched it in Mexico, where the Spanish scenes were not subtitled.  And although I do speak some Spanish, I didn't understand all of the Spanish-language dialog in the film.

What was the origin of Hollowface, and how was he finally defeated?

My best understanding of his defeat was that by sheer will power and/or knowledge of his nature, his power to frighten was lost.  Is this much accurate?

Comment: I just finished watching Intruders....i loved it!!! yes i agree, hollowface was a recreation of the boys fear from the night his father returned after a prison stint...its not very often i am truly captivated and satisfied by a movie such as this!

Comment: I agree with the above answers. I was disappointed with the movie still.. it just seemed predictable. Especially because they made that construction worker fall. It was kind of "the answer" or "the spoiler" for me. I like the story and the idea behind the movie though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The movie opens with a young boy, Juan, in Spain having nightmares about
Hollowface, a monster with no face. The plot then moves to England, following John and his family.

It shows two parallel stories with a connection;Juan is actually John (Mia's father).

At the end, John realizes his Hollowface connection with his daughter. Hollowface is disguised as a monster to suppress post traumatic stress.

John's mom relocated to England to escape the death of Juan's father in Spain. John's biological father is Hollowface, who he created as the young Juan through storytelling. Mia and John shared a psychic connection, so Hollowface is a fabricated spirit.

John's biological father who was released from jail attempted to abduct him. As a result, Juan and the mom watch the father fall off the ledge and into cement/soil. The mom refused to confess to the priest about the traumatic event that caused Juan nightmares.

Original synopsis found at [Twist Endings](http://www.twistendings.com/2013/08/intruders-movie-with-twist.html).

Answer (score 1):

Based on our website, Intruders is a simple psychological thriller. Two parallel stories coincide, though John and Juan are the same person. Juan created the Hollowface character to deal with the PTSD he experienced. His mother went along with the story, knowing that something terrible happened. She disclosed the truth to avoid conflict.

Hollowface is a fake monster. He is essentially a plot device to keep the moviegoer interested in the trauma. The power of the mind can create any type of fear. John never fully recovered from his childhood fear. With the help of his mother, Juan created Hollowface as a child. We discover the truth once the mother appears in the twist ending.

The daughter and John defeat a fake monster brought on by fears and the mind. At any time, you too can invent a fear. This movie is a psychological thriller written to convey unresolved trauma originating from past events. Hollowface is fake. He is not like Freddie Krueger.

[TwistEndings.com](http://www.TwistEndings.com) (The site I'm affiliated with) to read more about Intruders.